# Firing events when window is moved

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, itunes

I am currently developing an iTunes plug-in and I need to have my WPF plug-in to stick beside the iTunes window when dragged, resized, etc. The goal is to have iTunes sticked to my wpf app side by side.

I am looking for a way to track the movement (resizing, moving) of another window (in my case iTunes). The iTunes COM for Windows SDK offers events on maximize and minimize, unfortunately there are no events for resizing and moving the window.

I have tried the win32 setParent function without no succes. I don't think it's the appropriate solution for my problem. I have searched thoroughly through out the web but didn't find nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [WINDOWPOS structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you're looking for.  [Other window structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may come in handy.

Some google searching turned up [another](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/61e5989f-8a8c-44e8-81ab-09f2e9731bc4) example, that doesn't use WINDOWPOS:

> 1, Invoke API FindWindow() to retrieve the window handle (Uuse SPY++
>   to get the two parameters ClassName & WindowName);
>
> 2, Invoke API
>   GetWindowRect() to retrieve the size & postion of the specified
>   window.
>
> Code Snippet
>
> ```
>     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
>     private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowName);
>
>     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
>     private static extern int GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out Rectangle rect);
>
>     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         string className = "yourClassName";
>         string windowName = "yourWindowName";
>
>         Rectangle rect;
>         IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(className, windowName);
>         GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect);
>     }
> ```

Comment: When I have my window handle, how can I add an event handler on it ?

Comment: I'm not finding any specific examples of this, but here are a couple of examples: [[1](http://blog.recelate.net/2012/11/21/win32api-snapping-to-screen-edges/), [2](http://dn.embarcadero.com/cn/print/26370)] of the "snapping" or "docking" behavior you're looking for